# C profiler gives wrong results

Tags: c, profiler

can you tell me please, what is wrong with this code **http://pastebin.com/A2upK4Lx**? Cause it gives me Runtime: 0.00000, and that is weird, because I didnt spot an error there. Is it possible, that the code is fine, but the code executes so fast, that even C cant print it out (but I think that is highly unlikely)?

thank you guys for answer.

Comment: If you measure the runtime using an external tool, what do you observe?

Comment: Also, initializing `start` in an `assert()` is not a good idea. Compile with `NDEBUG`, and all of a sudden the variable is no longer being initiailized.

Comment: If you place something like this in `main()`, you'll probably start seeing non-zero times: `{volatile unsigned long qwe = 0; while (qwe < 1000000000ULL) qwe++; }`.

Comment: haha, 0.7 seconds? well then the mystery is solved...my PC is just too fast to profile the hashing program :D

Comment: @LászlóCitrusNagy Then you should probably accept the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible, that the code is fine, but the code executes so fast, that even C cant print it out (but I think that is highly unlikely)?

No, that's very likely indeed. We're not anymore in the 70's, computers are **fast.**

Comment: but the hashing functions are helluva resource heavy, aren't they?

Comment: @LászlóCitrusNagy If the string to be hashes is passed in through `argv[]`, there's a good chance it's a short string like `"foo"` or `"hello world"`. Hashing a dozen of bytes won't take the OS down.

Comment: @LászlóCitrusNagy If you want to verify the timing is working properly, put in a simple test in your program.  Do something like sleep(2) (if sleep is valid on your platform, for windows you might need something like Sleep() instead, with a slightly different calling convention).   Then see if it reports a longer execution time.

Comment: the hashed string is thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog...I thought that this will make my PC sweat